# Determine the convergence of the following series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n}$

Now i know that this is alternating series which means that i should determine the  absolute convergence $|a_n|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n}$ but i don't know how to do it, d'Alembert's test isn't working Cauchy tests can't help here here either so i am out of ideas now.

Comment: If $n=1$, then the denominator will be $0$.

Comment: @choco_addicted I know, that's confusing too, but let's say it starts with $n=2$ and then look for answer, i will edit this in a moment. Thank you.

Comment: This is a hard one. Call $s_k$ the partial sums, and check that both $s_{2k}$ and $s_{2k+1}$ are convergent. In particular, your series is bounded... But I have no idea for convergence of the whole series...

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\Bigl(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigr)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\,\bigl(\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n\bigr)}.
\end{align}$$
Now:

- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges by Leibniz's criterion.
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n)}$ diverges.

The original series diverges.

Another way of seeing it is to observe that the sum of two consecutive terms behaves like $1/n$, so that the even partial sums do not converge.

Comment: -1 No, you cannot rearrange the terms because it is not absolutely convergent. In fact it converges.

Comment: @almagest I have not rearranged the terms. I have written the original series as the sum of a convergent series and a divergent series. What is your argument to prove convergence? You cannot use Leibniz's criterion because $1/(\sqrt n+(-1)^n)$ is not decreasing.

Comment: But you have rearranged the terms. You have separated out an infinite subsequence of negative terms and put them first.

Comment: @almagest No. If $a_n$ is the general term of the original series, I have written $a_n=b_n+c_n$ with $\sum b_n$ convergent and $\sum c_n$ divergent. Observe that neither $b_n$ nor $c_n$ are terms of the original series.

Comment: But you have then said that $\sum (b_n+c_n)=(\sum b_n)+(\sum c_n)$.

Comment: @almagest Yes, and that is not rearranging. If you prefer, write $c_n=a_n-b_n$. $\sum b_n$ is convergent; if $\sum a_n$ were convergent, so would be $c_n$. This is one of he first properties one studies about series.

Comment: This answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Yes. You are right. Adding even a conditionally convergent series to the series $\sum c_n$ term by term does not change its convergence. It is also true that $a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$ is approx $-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @almagest Would you please remove the down vote?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I tried to but it is blocked after 1 hour unless the answer is changed. So if you made a trivial change I could remove it.

Comment: --1 and +1 @JulianAguirre as promised!

Comment: @almagest Thak you.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n}= \sum_{n=2}^m\frac{(-1)^n(\sqrt{n} - (-1)^n)}{(\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n)(\sqrt{n} - (-1)^n)} \\ =\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}-1}{n -1}\\ = \sum_{n=2}^m\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n -1}- \sum_{n=2}^m\frac{1}{n -1}. $$

The first sum converges by Dirichlet and the second sum diverges.

Hence the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\frac 1{\sqrt n + (-1)^n} \sim \frac 1{\sqrt n}$$ and the latter series does not converge, neither does your $|a_n|$

a problem with your approach though is that since the absolute series does not converge, you can't conclude anything about the series with term $a_n$

Comment: What am i supposed to do then? Cani use Leibniz's test for alternative series, i mean $a_n>0$ and $a_n>a_{n+1}$ and $\lim_n \rightarrow \infty a_n =0$ so then by this test it means that it is convergent but it is conditionally convergent. Am i right?

Comment: @cdummie No, because the series is not decreasing. It is easy to show, Note that the fact that is decreasing should only hold in a neighborhood of $\infty$, so to show this is not enough to look at a particular case $n=2$ and conclude that it is not decreasing

Comment: But, what can i do then?

Comment: @cdummie You have to find some other way. You can 1) Try to compute the partial sums for a general $N$ and then taking limit as $N \to \infty$ (Note: usually this is too hard, but one can always try) 2) Try to use Cauchy's criterion for convergence of a series, which works also for non-positive series (This is also quite complex in this case) 3) Be creative! Other two people provided creative answers; what they did was break up the sum so that $\sum a_n = \sum b_n + \sum c_n$, where $\sum b_n$ converges while $\sum c_n$ doesn't. This implies that $\sum a_n$ diverges and you're done.

Comment: i saw that now, guess that if standard methods aren't working, then i should try some tricks in order to simplify it.

Comment: @cdummie Yes, indeed :-)

Answer (score -1):

Compare the first two terms, $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} +1}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-1}$: the sequence is not monotone decreasing, so the alternating series test does not apply

Comment: -1 It should only be monotone decreasing in a neighborhood of $\infty$; the fact that for $n=2$ is not is irrelevant :-)

Comment: True, alternating series test does not apply.  However, this does not answer the question of whether the series converges anyway.

Comment: @Ant: this holds for arbitrary $n$: if we compare $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + (-1)^n}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}$, after some algebra we arrive at 1 on LHS and $2(-1)^n (\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}) on RHS, which is oscillating.

Comment: Hence Leibniz criteria cannot be applied in this case

Comment: I know! I also said so in the comment below my answer :-)  I was pointing out that saying that the first two terms are not decreasing does not imply anything regarding the application of Leibniz criteria, and you have to make the calculations with a general $n$